# Nodejs encrypted comunnication with frontend (javascript)

Tags: node.js, encryption, communication, frontend, backend

I am sending a JSON with some important data to the frontend using Nodejs. 
If i enter in the explorer the url of the JSON i am requesting the json data is displayed. 
Also, if i firebug the website i am able to view the POST or GET requests with that important data.

I need a way of communicating with from backend to frontend but being encrypted so that nobody can never see that important data.

I am thinking of using google fusion tables (excel in the cloud) to achieve this, but i am sure there must be a simpler solution.

Regards,

Comment: *nobody can never see that important data* But how will your front-end use the data if it can't be decrypted?

Comment: Use SSL, only who requests the data is able to see it. Or do you want to hide it from the requesting user?

Comment: that's a request that will be done when the website is loaded and the information read will be used to build some dynamic tips so that users can figure out the data...if there is a way that the user can get that info..the game is over before it starts...i need to hide it from all the users, even the requester...

Comment: If it is possible for the browser to decode it and render it, it will be just as possible for a user to do so. There really isn't any easy way around that.